# What is the file /tmp/dumps/user_stdout.txt?

Tags: filesystem

I'm reading a book about the command line and am poking around my system.  I noticed a file inside `/tmp/dumps` called 'user_stdout.txt', 'user' being my first name.  This text file contained chats/stats/game maps/other info all from a steam game session I played last night.  Just wondering what and why files are dumped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a standard system file. Any application can write to the `/tmp` directory; it's meant for temporary files only. Given the content, presumably  the developer of that game (or a library that this game uses) decided to write some stuff in this file. It might be debugging information that they forgot to remove before distributing the software.

Any well-written program would not use a file name such as this since there's a risk of collision between two applications. End-user software should be writing such logs under the user's home directory anyway.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the folder 'dumps' inside /tmp is not a standard system folder, correct?  Both the folder 'dumps' and the text file inside dumps, user_stdout.txt, were both put in /tmp either by the steam application, the game (Fist Full of Frags), or both, right?

Comment: @G19shooter Yes, it's this one application that's doing it, and shouldn't.